# Unable to create jar from eclipse in proper way

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, entry-point

I have problem to made executable jar using eclipse. I export project to jar by:

File>Export>Java>Runnable Jar file, Next, Finish. When I try to exec this jar i get error: "Error: Could not find or load main class ...".

I have three folders with code in my project. In one of them is `(default package)` and there is Main class with `public static void main(String[] args)` function. How to check what is wrong with export process and what make to sure that Main class is entry point of jar? All of thees three folder are in build path (as Java Build Path>Source says).

Comment: The problem was incorrect run command. I was using `java [name]` instant of `java -jar [name]`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to build and run first so you create a configuration.

Then, when you go export, in the same screen you are asked the path to save to, there is another option that lets you pick the main to attach to your jar. If you haven't done a build and run yet, you won't see this one.

**Select runnable jar for your export**

[image]

**This is probably where your issue is. Select the proper main**

[image]

Comment: OK, I'm sure that I made everything just like you say. Now I have new clean workspace with only one project and only one `Lunch configuration`, and effect is same.

//
`File>Export>Runnable Jar file`, `Next`. I select only one existing `Launch configuration` which is `Main - Game` (project name is Game), I sett existing `Export destination` path and press `Finish`. Error message is same.

Comment: The name that goes in the top box is the class name that has your main.  Make sure to build and run the program FROM that main

Comment: Thanks for help, but everything with exporting was OK. The problem was caused by incorrect run command. I was using `java [name]` instant of `java -jar [name]`.